# For 3 Language Packaging, does font size need to be the same?

Tags: fonts, text

when dealing with 3 language artwork, would the French and Spanish text need to be the same as the English text? Can the translations be smaller font size than English? Or does all text need to be the same size?

I think it needs to be the same size, but looking for some other input.

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Comment: What is the packaging for? There are different rules for food, alcohol, etc...

Comment: Packaging is for general art supplies - no food or consumable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my work I usually downsize all fonts to match the smallest one needed to accommodate the Spanish and German one (THOSE GERMANS AND THEIR LONG WORDS WITHOUT HYPHENATION).

It's bad idea to make English one bigger and to stand out because people will complain (THOSE FRENCHS AND THEIR SUPERIORITY COMPLEX).

Also it looks better.

Comment: hmmmm... humour was it?

Comment: Hmm, don't get the downvotes. OK, the jokes aren't that funny and could do without the shouty bits, but the advice is sound.

Comment: This answer suggests that resizing the font is okay even tho it clearly destroys any good design if done carelessly

Comment: It's not a sign of a good design if it's designed for multiple languages but look good only in one. If it was designed in and for only one language it means it needs redesigning.

Answer (score 0):

No set rule about this and probably something the client will ultimately decide based on their markets, etc. But if the size of the packaging allows you to, these should probably be the same size.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon what country these languages will appear.  If this will appear in Canada, for example, then, by law, all languages must be printed in the same font size, as no language may be more prominent than the other, though English must appear first, then French. There is no such law in the US.